# Installing Ubuntu on MSI

Tags: system-installation, compatibility

My notebook is MSI S12T with AMD E1-2100 APU with Radeon processor. Memory 4GB and it has now a version of Windows 10 32Bit (previously was 64bit Windows 8.1).

My question is;

1. Does Ubuntu support the configuration mentioned above?
2. I completely want to remove Windows 10 and use UBUNTU, single boot. I heard many friends failed to install Ubuntu in their drives. What if I encounter the same problem?

Comment: burn the ubuntu iso file onto a DVD then boot from it picking the LiveCD mode where you try it out before doing any install ... if the LiveCD works fine then you know your hardware will run linux just fine

Comment: I tried LIVE mode, it opened UBUNTU but WIFI, WebCam did not work. Other features work properly. I went to MSI support site to ask for support and they suggest to contact LINUX forum.

May be there are other issues too that I have not studied carefully. Right now I am searching driver support for these two devices? WIFI and WebCam.